# How to multiply each number in a State?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to write a code with JS and React. 
In the App.js file i have set the state for some components, like this:

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    leafs: [
      {
        id: "1",
        percent: "",
        win: false,
      }
    ],
    result: [
      {
        winProbability: "0",
      }
    ]
  };
```

It is possible to add many "leafs" and add a different "percent" in each of them. When a button is clicked, I want to multiply the percent (if it is true) with the percent in each "leaf". So if the percent is 3 in one leaf, 4 in another, and 5 in the last, I want the answer to be 60 (3*4*5).

Here is the function:

```
  calculate = () => {
    leafs: this.state.leafs.map(leaf => {
      if (leaf.win === true) {
        var sum = 1;
        for (var i = 0; i < leaf.percent.length; i++) {
          sum = sum * +leaf.percent[i];
        }
        console.log(sum);
        this.setState({
          result: this.state.result.map(result => {
            result.winProbability = sum;
            return result;
          })
        });
      }
    });
  };
```

Whit the numbers as described above, the console shows 3 in one line, then 4, and then 5. So what am I doing wrong? I wold really appreciate som help!

Comment: You are looping through the wrong thing. Try this: 

calculate = () => {
    leafs: this.state.leafs.map(leaf => {
      if (leaf.win === true) {
        var sum = 1;
        for (var i = 0; i < leaf.length; i++) {
          sum = sum * +leaf[i].percent;
        }
        console.log(sum);
        this.setState({
          result: this.state.result.map(result => {
            result.winProbability = sum;
            return result;
          })
        });
      }
    });
  };

Comment: I did not work.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a reduce function, instead of mapping. You are iterating over the array with map there and resetting the sum to 1 at the beginning of every iteration. I assume you want to achieve something like this:

```
calculate = () => {
  this.setState({
    result: Object.assign({}, this.state.result, {
      winProbability: this.state.leafs.reduce(
        (winProb, leaf) => (leaf.win ? winProb * leaf.percent : winProb),
        1
      )
    })
  });
};
```

Comment: @Nick I edited it to now produce the same result as the calculate function in the next answer.

Answer (score 1):

This worked, but there is probably a better way:

```
  calculate = () => {
    var sum = [];
    leafs: this.state.leafs.map(leaf => {
      if (leaf.win === true) {
        sum.push(leaf.percent);
      }
    });
    var sumPrint = 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < sum.length; i++) {
      sumPrint = sumPrint * +sum[i];
    }
    this.setState({
      result: this.state.result.map(result => {
        result.winProbability = sumPrint;
        console.log(sumPrint);
        return result;
      })
    });
  };
```